# Form redirection with multiple variables

Tags: php

I found a [wonderful example](http://phptutorial.codepoint.net/php_redirection) on form redirection when there is an error with the form elements. In validation.php the system checks if there is an error and if it's true it redirects the user to the form page.
My question is what if I have more than one form element?

As you see I renamed user_name to app_name and I added a new variable (adtext) so now I get two error messages when both form elements have some error (right now they not equal to a certain word), but I don't know what to do with the $query_string variable so the url would contain the second variable and its value as well.

This is how the url of the form page (adparameters.php) looks like when I click the submit button and there is an error with $appname:

/adparameters.php?appname=aa&error=App%20name%20is%20requiredAd%20text%20is%20required

```
<?php
# validate.php

$appname = trim($_POST['appname']);
$adtext = trim($_POST['adtext']);
$error = '';

if ($appname != 'myapp') $error = 'App name is required<br />';
if ($adtext != 'mytext') $error = $error . 'Ad text is required<br />';


$query_string = '?appname=' . $appname;


$server_dir = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\') . '/';

header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');

if ($error != '') {

   // Back to register page
   $next_page = 'adparameters.php';

   // Add error message to the query string
   $query_string .= '&error=' . $error;

   // This message asks the server to redirect to another page
   header('Location: http://' . $server_dir . $next_page . $query_string);
}
// If Ok then go to confirmation
else $next_page = 'confirmation.php';

/*
Here is where the PHP sql data insertion code will be
*/
// Redirect to confirmation page
header('Location: http://' . $server_dir . $next_page . $query_string);
?>
```

The greatness of this code is that if I type something in the first input type object and it doesn't equal 'myapp' it is still filled with the text after redirection. That's what I want with the second object as well.

Comment: Well if you have error in your second input field you can do something like this $query_string = '?appname=' . $appname . '&addtext='.$adtext;

Comment: @vodich is correct.  A side note: you may be better off using AJAX to validate the form before sending it to the server.  That way if there is an error the user can find out before they send it to the server.  Or, for your very simple case you could validate it with javascript, and not let them submit until they fix the errors.

Comment: These are not objects, your merely wanting to concatenate a string as a querystring.

Comment: @vodich: I have done this already but it looks like I made a mistake then. Add this as a solution please.

Comment: @Boundless: I validate with javascript but we both it's for user friendliness and server side validation is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to send them in a $_SESSION.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form'] = array();
$_SESSION['form']['myapp'] = 'App Error Code';
$_SESSION['form']['adtext'] = 'AdText Error Code';
```

Then on the new page you would get the values as an array;

```
session_start();
$form_error =  $_SESSION['form']['myapp'];
$form_error =  $_SESSION['attext']['myapp'];
```

If you insist on using GET parameters why not append them on with the `&` character.

```
?field1=one&field2=two
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a session.  You are handling everything on the server, you don't need to create a session.  Sessions are needed if you want to keep track of a user, and data associated with them.  I don't think this applies here.

Comment: @Boundless Sorry, I disagree. Sessions are for handling a browsing session, and a form submission is most definitely part of a browsing session!

Comment: I agree with your comment.  I disagree with a session being needed for simplistic form submission, with a simplistic site, which this post describes. We will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Guys is this a better approach than the one I am using? Why?

Answer (score -2):

I woldn't do it the way you do it but if you want it like that just change few things

```
  if ($appname != 'myapp') $error = 'App name is required<br />';
  if ($adtext != 'mytext') $error .= 'Ad text is required<br />';//note contatenation


   $query_string = '?appname=' . $appname .'&addtext='.$adtext;
```

Comment: don't forget the ampersand ...  $query_string = '?appname=' . $appname .'&addtext='.$adtext;

Comment: why wouldn't you do it the way I do it?

Comment: Also, $error .= $error . 'Ad text is required<br />' should be:   $error .= 'Ad text is required<br />' -OR- $error = $error . 'Ad text is required<br />' ... Using $error .= $error ... will give you 'Ad text is required<br />Ad text is required<br />

Comment: Yea I was in a hurry I edited it now. @erdomester - I prefer to do js validation to check if fields are empty before posting to page that is supposed to do insert or whatever. No need to post the form if fields are empty right?

Comment: If javascript is turned off then I need server validation

Comment: Off course , you don't relly on js it is there just for the purpose of doing simple pre-validation before the real thing. If you work on large website every refresh of the page counts

Comment: Is it possible to do with this that if there is also a file upload option and the user selected a file but left an input field empty, so he is redirected to the page, the file upload field would have the file name and the user wouldn't have to select the file again?